# Is it possible to get the last path of a url using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

Is possible to get the last value in URL results in the following string:

```
http://www.example.com/snippets/rBN6JNO/
```

My RegEx is matching the whole string

```
\/.+\/
```

It matches:

```
//www.example.com/snippets/rBN6JNO/
```

I want to get the last value:

```
rBN6JNO
```

Or should I use another method?

Comment: use split by "/" and access last/last second value

Comment: You can try `(\w+)\/?$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/([a-z\d]+)(\/*|)$/i
```

And see "$1"

Comment: you have to check whether it has parameter or not. \?+

Answer (score 4):

You can split your URL with `/`, and then access the last object of the splited URL.

Try the following:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/snippets/rBN6JNO";
var splitedUrl = url.split('/');   
var lastPath = splitedUrl[splitedUrl.length - 1]; //rBN6JNO
```

Comment: Perhaps, it is a good idea to remove any trailing `/`  before splitting: `url.replace(/\/+$/, '').split('/')`.

Comment: Yep, could be a good idea. It will make `splitedUrl[]` simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using javaScript you can do it,

```
var URL_STRING = 'http://www.example.com/snippets/rBN6JNO/'
URL_STRING.split('/').slice(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid to create an array, you can do this with string methods only - using [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```
s = s.replace(/\/$/,"");
console.log(s.substr(s.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
```