# How to get characters from second last index using indexof in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, lastindexof

```js
var absoluteURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6262169/vikas-kohli"     
var n = absoluteURL.lastIndexOf('/');
var result = absoluteURL.substring(n + 1);
//alert(result);
console.log(result);
```

Here I get the result like 'vikas-kohli' as I am using lastIndexOf.

Now if someone wants to get characters from second last index, or it may be 3rd last index, then how can I get this?

I hope I am able to explain my question well

Comment: How about split using `/` and then fetch necessary values and join them. `a=url.split('/'); final=a.slice(a.length - n).join('/')`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022542/is-possible-to-get-last-path-of-regexp-in-url/42022591#42022591

Answer (score 6):

- Insteadof using `lastIndexOf('/')` use string [**split('/')**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

```js
var absoluteURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6262169/vikas-kohli"     
var splittedStr = absoluteURL.split('/');
console.log(splittedStr);
```

- Then get the required element from an array.

  var res = splittedStr[splittedStr.length-n]; // n: 1,2,3..
  cosnole.log(res);

**DEMO**

```js
var absoluteURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6262169/vikas-kohli"     
var splittedStr = absoluteURL.split('/');
console.log(splittedStr[splittedStr.length-2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var absoluteURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6262169/vikas-kohli"     
var results = absoluteURL.split('/');
var result = results[results.length-2];
alert(result);
```

Comment: This fetches the data from the last index.

Comment: 6262169/vikas-kohli i need like this how can do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()` on the `window.location.pathname`:

```js
var locPath = "users/6262169/vikas-kohli"; // window.location.pathname;
var arr = locPath.split('/');

arr.forEach(function(item){
  console.log(item);
});
```

With specific indexes:

```js
var locPath = "users/6262169/vikas-kohli"; // window.location.pathname;
var arr = locPath.split('/');

console.log('last::::',arr[arr.length-1]);
console.log('second last::::', arr[arr.length-2]);
```

Or subsequent `pop()` can give you last item of array:

```js
var locPath = "users/6262169/vikas-kohli"; // window.location.pathname;
var arr = locPath.split('/');

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 0), '<---last::::popped-->',arr.pop());
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 0), '<-----second last::::popped--->', arr.pop());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sth like this?

```
var absoluteURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6262169/vikas-kohli"     
var n = 2 //second last
var arr = absoluteURL.split('/')
console.log(arr[arr.length-n])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split your URL with `/`:

```js
var absoluteUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6262169/vikas-kohli";window.location.pathname;
var splitedUrl = absoluteUrl .split('/');
console.log(splitedUrl);
```

Then get the element you want in the array.

Answer (score 0):

IndexOf or something like that may not what you need. You can use split instead.

```js
var absoluteURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6262169/vikas-kohli";
var partNo = 3;
var parts = absoluteURL.split('/');
alert(parts[parts.length - partNo]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop would do the trick.

```
var absoluteURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6262169/vikas-kohli"    
var n = absoluteURL.indexOf('/');
absoluteURL = absoluteURL.substring(n+2); // Becasue there are two / first

for(i = 0; i < x ; i++) // x should be such that if it is 1, then only the last string will come, if 2, then the last two strings
{
    n = absoluteURL.indexOf('/');
    absoluteURL = absoluteURL.substring(n+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if u can get nth Index from user u can use this

```
 var nthIndex = 2;
 var absoluteURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6262169/vikas-kohli"  
 for (i = 0; i < nthIndex; i++) {   

        var n = absoluteURL.lastIndexOf('/');           
            absoluteURL = absoluteURL.substring(0,n);}
alert(absoluteURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate string from the index you want after splitting it with `/`

```js
var absoluteURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6262169/vikas-kohli";     
var n = 2; // set the index from where you want to get characters
var arr = absoluteURL.split('/');
var a = [];
for(var i=n,j=0; i>=0; i--,j++){
  a[j] = arr[arr.length-i];
}
console.log(a.join('')); // you can join it with any character
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add a function to do that ourselves.

Add below code snippet:

```
String.prototype.nIndexOf = function (char, index) {
if (index >= this.split(char).length)
    return -1;
else
    return this.split(char, index).join(char).length;
}
```

Then you can use this as following:

```
var absoluteURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/6262169/vikas-kohli"     
var n1 = absoluteURL.nIndexOf('/', 4);
var n2 = absoluteURL.nIndexOf('/', 5);
var result = absoluteURL.substring(n1 + 1, n2);
alert(result);
```